# Program for solving mathematical equations

Tags: linux

Do you know a program that can solve equatation by given variable? And where I can tell the program which variables are parameters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Software to write and manipulate mathematical equations](http://superuser.com/questions/63672/software-to-write-and-manipulate-mathematical-equations)

Comment: Have you tried [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)?

Comment: But something offline more mathematical with indexes etc.

Comment: You keep deleting your comments before anyone has a chance to respond to them. If the possible duplicate does not help with your problem, then please edit your question to be more specific. Some examples might help too.

Comment: I need a program which could from: xa/b=5a give me x=5b (where b is param for programming use), but the equatations will be more complicated and sometimes Simultaneous.

Answer (score 7):

take a look at this: http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/tour_algebra.html

other possibilities which come to my mind:

**commercial:**

- [Maple](http://www.maplesoft.com/products/Maple/index.aspx)
- [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/)
- [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/?s_cid=global_nav) with [Analytical Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/analytical-solution.html)

**free:**

- [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/)
- [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Scilab is another possibility: http://www.scilab.org

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Wolfram-Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) online (does an excellent job) or use [Microsoft Mathematics](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9caca722-5235-401c-8d3f-9e242b794c3a) (simply amazing).  The best thing about Microsoft Mathematics is that, for many problems, it shows you the steps it took to solve the equation.  They used to charge for Microsoft Mathematics, but it looks like it is free now.